# AJAX: Get two documents

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am using this AJAX code to loading a PHP page to change the `ORDER BY` for a MySQL clause.
Also i have a function called `getDESC`.

Now I want to expand this two codes that there are get two PHP documents.  These are katbox with kate.php. Is that possible and can you help to write this code?

```
function getASC()
{
    xmlHttp = CreateXmlHttpObjet();

    if (xmlHttp == null)
        return;

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        document.getElementById('ascbox').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    };

    xmlHttp.open('GET', 'asc.php', true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: ehrm... just execute it twice, with another target file?

Comment: Why not just use an include inside `asc.php`?

Comment: i have in my sql code two variables and i want to switch each variable with two buttons. these buttons are starting the ajax functions

Comment: i have desc, asc and category1 and category2. the idea was to loading four different ajax codes with different variable combinations

Answer (score 0):

Just update your function like so, now you can call `getAJAX('ascbox', 'asc.php')` and `getAJAX('katbox', 'kate.php')`

```
function getAJAX(id, php)
{
    xmlHttp = CreateXmlHttpObjet();

    if (xmlHttp == null)
        return;

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    };

    xmlHttp.open('GET', php, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```